# Access violation in printing out float value using printf

Tags: floating-point, embedded, vxworks

I get runtime Access Violation when I try to run the following line:

```
float x;
x = 29.600;
printf("%f", x);
```

This is a `*.C` file within CPP project, running in kernel space.
OS is `vxworks 6.7`

On the other hand, integer values are being printing out just fine.
Also if it might help, the float values are print out for single time.During the initialization of the full application.
Task has floating point support, so that should not be problem as well.
Same section of code is running fine on windows platform/MVCE

**NOTA BEFORE CLOSING BECAUSE OF NO MVCE OR EVIDENTLY CORRECT C CODE :**

This question is about **kernel mode** on an **embedded system**. A MVCE should at least contains kernel code and all the kernel developping environment reference.
Also in kernel developpement it is not really surprising *because of kernel limitation for performance improvement* that some perfectly correct code breaks in the context.

Comment: You only show a piece of code that should work. Please try to bild a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. As currently written you question is off topic.

Comment: That's the reason why I ask for a MVCE ...

Comment: I suspect you have undefined behaviour in your other code.

Comment: Could this be some embedded system that doesn't support printing floating point numbers? Especially in kernel space?

Comment: You're saying "kernel space". I've worked inside quite a few kernels and I can only recall one that allowed floating point math. It makes context switching quite expensive and kernels usually don't need floating point math.

Comment: @gnasher729 , yes this is embedded application. Floating point calculation is not a problem,then why is printing out is a problem?, i do not know any such rule or exception that is why i am posting it here

Comment: @SergeBallesta Rest of the code is huge, so cannot write down everything.Also this is the line that is giving the problem, if you read the whole question, integer values are running fine, so rest of the code should not be a problem. And as mentioned in question, this is vxWorks so MVCE is out of question.

Comment: "*Also this is the line that is giving the problem, if you read the whole question, integer values are running fine, so rest of the code should not be a problem.*" this is an invalid conclusion from your premisses.

Comment: @dom0 

'int x;
x = 29;
printf("%d", x);'


<- this code works...I fail to see why it is invalid conclusion, of whether i need to produce the whole code. I repeat the calculation of floating point numbers are not a problem,printing out is...

Comment: @SergeBallesta,@FDinoff "off topic?""a problem that can no longer be reproduced?". On a PC running windows/Linux same issue cannot be replicated and it gave no issues when i tested on windows/linux. The question is for those who have faced similar issues.If you cannot understand the question please be open to the fact that its a lack of your own understanding, and do not resort to some "rules"..i do not intend to offend anyone

Comment: @sodiumSpark : After the comments from Art and gnasher729, I begin to understand your problem, I admit that I was not cautious enough on the **running in kernel space. OS is vxworks**, and I think other close voters read same as i did. I'm afraid your question did not insist enough on this point. As Art, I can remember that in kernel compilation, it was stated that the kernel used a stripped out library not allowing for floating point formatting. I'm going to vote for re-open, but IMHO you should edit your question to insist on the kernel part.

Comment: In an embedded application, if this is your only FP, the FP routines may _not_ be included in `printf()`. Add code the explicitly does FP math. `printf("%f", x*x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

In the Kernel configuration (project explorer), windriver workbench explicitly provides option to add support for floating point math , this solved the whole issue.